# Apply "technologies" to queried document automatically

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am making hobbistic "civlike" game using node.js+mongoose+websocket (it's only back-end - mostly for training), and i stuck on "technologies" - don't know how to implement them.

First idea was "overload" a exec() method and there add something like:

```
Techs.apply(result);
```

,but it can't be done like that - it's asynchronous and exec() has no acces to returned docs.

Without it i have to every time i query for docs apply them manually - but i don't think its best way to do it, maybe im wrong or it's only way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I can't figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's asynchronous, you have to deal with the document in your callback function. I think what you are trying to do is this.

## Fetch the document by it's ID

```
    // docId is the _id passed from the client
    Techs.findById(docId, function(err, doc) {

        // This code executes after we've returned from MongoDB with the answer
        // Now you can either updated it some code like this
        doc.title = 'new title';

        // Then after you've updated you need to call the save() function
        doc.save();

        // Now send the response to the client
        response.end(doc); // this will send the JSON of the doc to the client

    });
```

### OR

## Search for one document by a field (type:'iphone')

```
    // Find a document based on a query
    Techs.findOne({type: 'iphone' }, function(err, doc) {

        // This code executes after we've returned from MongoDB with the answer
        // Now you can either updated it some code like this
        doc.title = 'new title';

        // Then after you've updated you need to call the save() function
        doc.save();

        // Now send the response to the client
        response.end(doc); // this will send the JSON of the doc to the client

    });
```